# Drag and Drop an object with pause before the drop

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir for automated testing, essentially this project is a task manager.

tasks drop in to a day of the week but it requires a short pause for the task to be hovered over that specific day for it to be recognised by the javascript.

At the moment this is only an issue with firefox, chrome is fine.

So my question is, can you drag and drop but hold the element over an area before the drop?

currently using this function:

```
 dragTask.drag_and_drop_on dropTask
```

Comment: Do you know of a page that illustrates the problem (ie a page that solutions could be tested against)?

Comment: @JustinKo sadly I don't think I can share the exact code etc.. I can only really describe.  Is there any other way I can maybe help provide a little extra info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same question some time ago with Watir-WebDriver and initially came to monkey patching  Selenium ActionBuilder. It was smth like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class ActionBuilder

      def hold(timeout)
        @devices.merge!(:self => self) unless @devices[:self]
        @actions << [:self, :sleep, timeout]
        self
      end

    end # ActionBuilder
  end # WebDriver
end # Selenium


begin
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.goto "data:text/html,#{DATA.read}"
  button_1 = browser.button(id: "button1")
  button_2 = browser.button(id: "button2")
  browser.driver.action.
                 click_and_hold(button_1.wd).
                 move_to(button_2.wd).
                 hold(3).
                 release.
                 perform
ensure
  browser.close
end


__END__

<html>
  <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
  <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
</html>
```

Comment: I gave this a try but for some reason that I'm sure of there was a pause before the drag and drop action instead of during?

Comment: You mean it waited before dragging?

Comment: Yea that seems to be what's happening sadly

Comment: You're right. I don't have any example right now to test, neither have I old code, but updated version should work. Please, give it a try and let me know if it's ok.

Comment: Cheers for the help but sadly the variables mouse, keyboard have no values, I'm unsure what to set them as.  Currently getting the error that 0 for 2 inputs

Comment: Sorry my bad, haven't tested it. I updated answer and this time it should definitely work.